# Convert an assembly to equivalent c code

Tags: c, assembly

Please help me to convert the following code to equivalent C code. Thanks in advance. This module returns an uint value. The code is given below.

```
inline uint jpeg_decoder::huff_extend(uint i, int c)
{
  _asm
  {
    mov ecx, c
    mov eax, i
    cmp eax, [ecx*4+extend_mask]
    sbb edx, edx
    shl edx, cl
    adc eax, edx
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply . I didn't try anything because I am not comfortable with asembly codes . i can understand the variable c is put in to the ecx register variable i in to eax register but why not other registers that i cant figure out , and how can i return a value from this method that i also cant figure out.Please help me.

Comment: The [Intel Architecture Software Developer's Manual](http://download.intel.com/design/intarch/manuals/24319101.pdf) is the canonical reference for x86 assembly. Try using it to understand this assembly code, and come back with *specific* questions about parts you don't understand.

Comment: @Li-aungYip Come on, that question is very specific. And actually it isn't that hard, and answerable in 5 minutes (possibly not for you, but there are many clever people on SO), so no need to post a link to a technical reference which won't help him at all

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are not familiar with the `sbb` and `adc` instructions, which are *subtract with borrow* and *add with carry*.
`sbb edx,edx` is a common construct to set `edx` to -1, if the carry is set - a instruction to negate the carry flag and move it into a register (something the developer manual won't tell you).
The shift instruction shifts into the carry bit again - only if there actually is a shift.
So the function is doing basically:

```
if ( extend_mask[c] > i ) 
    return i + (c != 0);
else
    return i;
```

Comment: Thank you very much , it will rwally help me.